# javascript class object, method in keyevent doesnt works

Tags: javascript, oop

Why `method1` works when direct in init but doesn't work when triggered by keyevent.
on 32,39 keyevent it doesnt works, but on keyevent 37 it works. So, the function should work.

`init` function also works, for example when I init `method2`, while method is running `method1`. This works, but why when `keyevent` it doesn't work?

```
function myClass() {
    this.method1 = function method1(word) {
        alert(word)
    }
    this.method2 = function method2(word) {
        this.method1(word);
    }
    this.shortcutKey = function shortcutKey() {
        document.onkeydown = function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 39) {
                this.method1("undirect");
            } else if (event.keyCode == 37) {}
        }
    }
    this.init = function init() {
        this.method2("direct init");
        this.shortcutKey();
    }
    this.init();
}
var object = new myClass();
```

Comment: `this` refers to `document` inside of the "keydown" event. Store a reference to the `myClass` object by using something like `var obj = this;` **before** setting `.onkeydown`. Then, inside the handler, when you need to reference the object's methods, use `obj.method1("whatever");`

Comment: I avoid the omission of semi-colons to prevent surprising automatic inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` keyword has a different value in different contexts.

Inside a callback `this` will must likely refer to the `window` object [except in strict mode](https://coderwall.com/p/jes4dw). When strict mode is enabled `this` will be `undefined` outside the objects context.

The problem is that the `onkeydown` event isn't executed in the context of `MyClass`. To fix this you will need to create a reference to the intended context like:

```
this.shortcutKey = function shortcutKey() {
    var self = this; // create reference to context

    document.onkeydown = function(event) {
        if( event.keyCode==32 || event.keyCode==39 ) {
            self.method1("undirect");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: It appears you can remove the useless `else if (event.keyCode == 37) {}` portion as it does nothing here.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the console you will see the error message

> TypeError: this.method1 is not a function [Break On This Error]
>
> this.method1("undirect");

The reason for this error is scoping.

The scoping of `this` is pointing to the wrong thing, you need to reference `this` outside of the keydown function. Take a look at the debug statements to see what `this` actually is.

```
this.shortcutKey = function shortcutKey() {
    var objScope = this;
    document.onkeydown = function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 32 ||
            event.keyCode == 39) {
            console.log("this", this);   /* this Window /_display/ */
            console.log("objScope", objScope);
            objScope.method1("undirect");
        } else if (event.keyCode == 37) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: "Take a look at the debug statements to see what this actually is."
thank for the tips. really useful tips.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
this.method1("undirect");
```

The scope of "this" changed. It does now refer to the function it is directly in.
To refer to the "this" you want to refer to, you have to assign it to a temp var first, in order to use the scope:

```
function myClass() {
    this.method1 = function method1(word) {
        alert(word)
    }
    this.method2 = function method2(word) {
        this.method1(word);
    }
    this.shortcutKey = function shortcutKey() {
        var that = this
        document.onkeydown = function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 39) {
                that.method1("undirect");
            } else if (event.keyCode == 37) {}
        }
    }
    this.init = function init() {
        this.method2("direct init");
        this.shortcutKey();
    }
    this.init();
}
var object = new myClass();
```

Comment: [quote]The scope of "this" changed. [/quote]
thank you. it works.